# ¿Como puedo evitar que se vuelva a cargar el contenido cuando dan clic atrás en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Estoy consumiendo una `api` `json` con `javascript` y añadiendo ese contenido en `html` usando `append` pero cuando se va a otra pagina y luego se da clic atrás en el navegador, el contenido se vuelve a recargar, por eso quiero saber de que manera podría evitar esto, este es el código `javascript` que estoy utilizando.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/api', true);
request.onload = function () {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(v => {
      const card = '<span><div class="card">v.content</div></span>';
      $("#data").append(card);
    });
  }else{
    console.log('Error al cargar el contenido');
  }
}
request.send();
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: Podrias borrar el contenido de `#data` cada vez que se regarga la pagina.

Comment: Lo que busco es que el contenido no se borre, ni se vuelva a recargar sino que se mantenga en el div cuando se da al botón atrás del navegador.